# Determine what versions of apps are installed in ecosphere

Tags: ios, app-store

This doesn't seem like a question for Ask Different so I asking it here.

We have a legacy version of our iOS app that uses old API calls now deprecated. Is there some sort of report from Apple that shows what users have the older versions of the app installed?

Comment: No. You can track the usage of your old apis on your server to get an idea of how many people are actively using the old version, but that is about all.